# Tensor product of sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be sheafs on a space $X$ then what is the relation of $\pi_1^* M\otimes \pi_2^* N$ and $\pi_1^* N\otimes \pi_2^* M$, where $\pi_i$ is the $i$ projection of $X\times X$

Comment: They're two sheaves on $X \times X$ which are sent to each other under the symmetry $X \times X \ni (x, y) \mapsto (y, x) \in X \times X$. You might call them the "transposes" of each other.

Comment: Crosspost: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209563/tensor-product-of-sheaf